# How to make text selectable on a QListView custom widget?

Tags: c++, qt, listview, qlistview, qtwidgets

### Context

TLTR: For a command-line console widget, I need to be able to select the texts on a `QListView` row.

In a similar way that your browser command-line (e.g. pressing F12 on Firefox and going to "Console", similar for Chrome, others). I am creating a command-line console for interacting with my application.

[image]

Each command and it result is pushed into a list above the input text-box, allowing each item to be drawn nicely and user-friendly:

- The text goes through a QSyntaxHighlighter
- Long lines, or multiple lines are elided
- Results which are objects can be expanded or collapsed
- etc..

Most of those goals are not yet implemented, but it's clear that I need a custom-widget to represent each row.

[image]

**Now, I need the text on that `QListView` item to be selectable**, and copiable.

### The problem

TLTR: Selecting the texts requiers to enter edit-mode, I don't like having to double-click first for selecting text.

Using a QStyledItemDelegate,
Overriding `paint`: I managed to have a draft of the apparence I need. But that apparence is mostly static, no interaction exists.
Overriding `createEditor` and `setEditorData`, the content can be edited. I can set the QTextEdit as `readOnly` and then, it is just selectable as required.

However, the list items needs to be double-clicked, or selected+clicked in order to get into edit-mode, and being able to select the text.
But, the user expects to select the text as it is, just by pressing+moving+relasing the mouse.

**The text should be selectable as it is, without double-clicking the row for getting into edit-mode**

### Some code

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QListView>
#include <QStyledItemDelegate>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QPaintEvent>
#include <QStandardItemModel>
#include <QTextEdit>

class CommandLineItemDelegate: public QStyledItemDelegate
{
    Q_OBJECT
    mutable QTextEdit m_editor;
public:
    void paint(QPainter *p, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const override
    {
        QRect rect(QPoint(0, 0), option.rect.size());

        m_editor.setPlainText( index.data().toString());
        m_editor.resize(option.rect.size());

        p->save();
        p->translate(option.rect.topLeft());

        m_editor.render(p, QPoint(), QRegion());
        p->restore();
    }

    QSize sizeHint(const QStyleOptionViewItem &, const QModelIndex &) const override
    {
        return QSize(200,50);
    }

    QWidget* createEditor(QWidget *parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const override
    {
        auto* edit = new QTextEdit(parent);
        edit->setGeometry(option.rect);
        edit->setReadOnly(true);

        return edit;
    }

    void setEditorData(QWidget *editor, const QModelIndex &index) const override
    {
        auto* textEditor = dynamic_cast<QTextEdit*>(editor);
        if (textEditor != nullptr)
        {
            textEditor->setPlainText(index.data().toString());
        }
    }

    void setModelData(QWidget *editor, QAbstractItemModel *model, const QModelIndex &index) const override
    {
        auto* textEditor = dynamic_cast<QTextEdit*>(editor);
        if (textEditor != nullptr)
        {
            model->setData(index, textEditor->toPlainText());
        }
    }
};

class CommandLineListView: public QListView
{
    Q_OBJECT
    CommandLineItemDelegate m_delegate;
    QStandardItemModel m_model;
public:
    explicit CommandLineListView( QWidget* parent=nullptr)
        : QListView(parent)
        , m_delegate()
    {
        setModel(&m_model);
        m_model.insertColumn(0);
        m_model.insertRows(0,3);
        m_model.setData(m_model.index(0,0),"var adri = function(a,b){return a+b; }; // function to sum");
        m_model.setData(m_model.index(1,0),"Math.PI");
        m_model.setData(m_model.index(2,0),"2+2");
        setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::SelectionMode::NoSelection); //Text selection, but no row selection.

        setItemDelegate(&m_delegate);
    }
};

#include "main.moc"

int main(int argn, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argn, argv);

    CommandLineListView list;
    list.show();

    app.exec();
}
```

[image]

As explained before, this "mostly" works, except that the user needs to double-click the row to enter edit-mode and selecting the text, which is not acceptable.

Comment: Have you changed you view's edit triggers?

Comment: I experimented with it yes, but all requires double-click, or select+click, or... None seems to give the appropriate "just select".

Comment: If even `QAbstractItemView::AllEditTriggers` does not make it for you, I suggest you override`QAbstractItemDelegate::editorEvent`. It is an alternative way to work with delegate by, for instance, allowing your `QTextEdit` to be created as soon as the mouse hovers an index.

Comment: @Atmo: I could make the selection to work, but having the editor to appear by hovering has huge side-effects on other widgets (lost of focus). I could not solve this.

Comment: Then try doing it when `event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress`; you can then cast the `QEvent*` to `QMouseEvent*`, get its position, create the editor, convert the position to the editor's coordinate and pass it to the editor (maybe by accepting it and creating a new event sent to `QWidget::mousePressEvent`). I expect the `MouseButtonPress` will avoid the lost of focus of other widgets.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have a ready-to-use solution; I would answer rather than post comments if I had; you will have to experiment a bit by yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Quick solution: easy, but not very performant for large list views**

A quick solution is to keep all the editors open, by calling [openPersistentEditor](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractitemview.html#openPersistentEditor) for each added row.

Note that this is not the most performant solution (for very large list view), but may be good enough for your use case.

**Alternative 1: Implement your own `QStyledItemDelegate`**

This allows full customisation of the formatting, but also requires that you implement the text selection feature yourself.

**Alternative 2: Use HTML**

Displaying it as HTML (which is probably what Chrome and Firefox do) allows you full customisation and using the built-in selection feature.

**Alternative 3: Use QML**

QML is often easier to (rapidly) create a custom user interface.

Comment: I am going to attempt your "Alternative 1", because I want to keep away from QML and also from having a full HTML engine just for this.

Comment: Note that `QLabel` and `QTextEdit` also supports basic HTML, which is probably enough for your use case and doesn't require a full blown (i.e. chromium/qtwebengine) web browser.